# Overflow Exceptions was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio

When I run below code in Visual Basic .Net 2013 I am facing this error "Overflow exceptions was unhandled". Kindly could you help me ?

```
Dim i As Short
Dim ch As Char  
Dim Number As integer
Dim Numbers() As String
Dim sb As New StringBuilder

txtCipherText.Text = txtCipherText.Text.Trim()
Numbers = txtCipherText.Text.Split(" ")

For i = 0 To Numbers.Length - 1
        Number = CInt(Numbers(i))
        Number = Number
        ch = Chr(Number  ^ 2011 Mod 3127) // THE ERROR IS HERE
        sb.Append(ch)
Next
```

Comment: What is the value of `Number`?

Comment: Why is this tagged as C# and not Visual Basic?

Comment: You have an overflow there. What are you trying to do and more to the point do you really need to raise numbers to the power of 2011? This is clearly going to overflow for anything bigger than 1...

Comment: I am trying to apply an RSA algorithm. my program is when I enter for example 'A'it takes an ASCII of A it is 65 and I encrypt it without any errors,but when I decrypt the to original A I should apply this code, So kindly what should I do in this case ?

Comment: Well the problem is that your number^2011 is too big to fit in an Integer which it needs to do as an intermediate step before applying mode 3127. You'll need to find a datatype more suited to these sorts of things. I assume that you are just implementing RSA algorithms to understand them rather than for any real code? The reason you didn't run into this problem when encrypting is that I assume your encryption coefficient is significantly smaller.

Comment: I assigned ULong data  type but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Integer (Int32) = 2,147,483,647 max value

Long (Int64) = 9,223,372,036,854,775,808

Double = 1.7*10^308

You might want to try NOT using a power of 2011
Using that high of a number doesnt boast any advantage over using, say, a power of 8

But honestly, I think you should consider a totally different way to encrypt.

Try this as a basis for your next encryption

```
ByteData As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Yourtext)
For Each part As Byte In ByteData
 'Encryption here
Next
```

Every byte can be represented by a number from 0-255. Try encrypting those numbers instead

This way you can encrypt text, and even entire files.

Use

```
YourText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteData)
```

To reverse it back into a string

Using that method I managed to create an encryption program that can turn any file into a bitmap image made to look like colorful television static, 4 bytes per pixel. It actually made a decent compression tool as well as encryption.

Comment: Actually thank you for your answer. I can use your code for encryption but specially I want to use RSA algorithm which it based on module formula.

Comment: No problem

If you want to use that algorithm, then there really is no option other than to use a smaller exponent, one that you can be sure to never overflow your data type.

If you know you wont be using negative numbers, then use unsigned data types.

Example ULong instead of Long

This means instead of ranging from say, -1,000,000 to 1,000,000 a variable might range from 0 to 2,000,000, effectively doubling the size of any data type

Comment: I just found something that might allow you to use mugh larger data types, I didnt look into it so you'd have to do that bit :P
https://gmplib.org/